# Safari 15 beforeunload shows exit alert but does not prevent navigation to cached pages. Bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, safari, apple-developer

The beforeunload event was intended to give a user a chance to save unsaved work before leaving a page. Safari appears unable to enable this feature.

To be clear: This original use case for beforeunload is exactly what I need. I am not trying to use beforeunload to trigger beaconing, empty localStorage, etc. I am not using Promise or await.

Using this test script on a blank HTML page in my Safari 15-16 browser, I am able to see the beforeunload alert, but the page navigates immediately to the next location:

```
    <script>
      function beforeUnloadListener(event) {
        if (true) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          event.returnValue = 'This message is ignored in modern browsers.';
          return event;
        }
        return null;
      }
      addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeUnloadListener, { capture: true });
    </script>
```

(I first must click into the window to make sure the browser detects interaction.)

1. if I close the browser window, the alert blocks the window from being closed
2. If I navigate to another CACHED page in safari, the alert is shown

I then WAIT a few seconds to observe the alert. What happens next in Safari is weird.

The alert does not block navigation. I am taken to the new page with the alert still being displayed. The alert is then "useless" in the sense that pressing the affirmative or negative buttons dismisses the alert, but has no other effect.

This is not the expected behavior in Chrome or Firefox. In these, the page will not navigate or cancel navigation until an alert option is clicked.

Is this by design? I doubt it, because leaving the alert up but navigating to another page is not an acceptable behavior.

Are there work-arounds? I can't find a way to support this feature in Safari.

Comment: You can not `event.preventDefault();` the page exiting, that line is useless. A lot of browsers force you to interact with the page for it to do things.

Comment: @epascarello [Per specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#beforeunloadevent) if you want a message to be shown to the user you need to call the `.preventDefault()` method of the BeforeUnloadEvent. And OP is describing that they did interact with the page, and even that they do see the message displayed.

Comment: I can't really reproduce on Safari v16.0 What I see however is that when using the browser's history to come back to the previous page, they kind-of remember that we accepted to leave the page before and won't show the message again. But that doesn't correspond to your description, since clicking "Stay on Page" always stays on page for me (both from navigation and reload).

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is MDN sample code. And yes, in my tests I click into the page before attempting to leave the page.

Comment: @Kaiido, thank you! I will check with Safari 16.

Comment: ... I noticed in the release notes for Safari 15 a number of bugs were fixed related to to beforeunload, but none related to my issue. I almost suspect my issue is a side effect of other fixes.

Comment: @Kaiido if you are interested see my updated description of the test. It's important to wait after the alert is shown when navigating off the test page. The oddest thing is you can clearly see that Safari is NOT blocking navigation. You would expect that all navigation would be suspended while the alert is shown.

Comment: The real issue here is the alert should block _navigation_ in general, not some part of navigation. It seems like Safari is blocking only a portion of the navigation cycle and cached pages are being passed.